# How to make Python 3.8.7 and Python 3.9.1 coexist in order to run different Python packages such as Pickle5 and Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pickle, chatbot

I am learning to build Chatbot in Python. The tutorial requires tensorflow, keras, pickle and nltk packages.

For installing tensorflow, keras and nltk. They only can be installed using Python 3.8 or earlier version

For Pickle5, it requires Python 3.9 or latest. I tried Pickle5 version 0.0.1. It can't be installed

How to make Python 3.8.7 and Python 3.9.1 coexist in order to run all packages (tensorflow, keras, pickle and nltk)?

Or how to install a pickle version, which can run on Python 3.8.7?

Thank you

Comment: This is exactly what virtual environments are for - look it up, and learn to love `virtualenv`

Comment: If you can use 3.9, why are you installing pickle5? Why not just use the built-in `pickle`module? It comes with Python, just do `import pickle`

Comment: Consider using a [venv](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#creating-virtual-environments). See link.

Answer (score 0):

Install `pyenv`, it's been very useful for me in similar situations:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: I think this is not the solution to ops underlying misunderstanding that `pickle5` is a backport of the builtin `pickle` module on Python 3.8